# Opensource or free online Oracle OLAP Server or Offline Oracle Cube file

Tags: oracle, olap, xmla

Is there any free online Oracle OLAP servers available for testing? or Is there any offline cube available for Oracle like (.cub) in SSAS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can download and use [Essbase](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/middleware/essbase/downloads/index.html) for free during development, but their site isn't exactly clear, and it's difficult to tell if this is actually true or not.

Comment: Yes you could, but it's a big PITA to install and configure.

Answer (score 1):

You could connect the Oracle OLAP cubes through Simba MDX provider.

Refer, http://www.simba.com/news/Simba-Releases-MDX-Provider-for-Oracle-OLAP.htm for more.